# Dexie.js query error

Tags: javascript, dexie

Following query throws error:

```
  DB.classes
    .where("name")
    .anyOf(["John", "Rick"])
    .or("nickname")
    .anyOf(["Joe", "Bill"])
    .and("isDummy")
    .equals("1")
    .toArray().then(()=>{})
```

How can I rewrite the query in correct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB.classes
.where("name")
.anyOf(["John", "Rick"])
.or("nickname")
.anyOf(["Joe", "Bill"])
.and(clazz => clazz.isDummy === 1)
.toArray().then(()=>{})
```